# What does the symbol Continuation do?

Tags: output-formatting, output, undocumented

There is a symbol `Continuation` (residing in the `` System` `` context).  There is no usage or documentation for this symbol.  `Information` brings up:

```
?Continuation
```

> System`Continuation
>
> ```
> MakeBoxes[Continuation[_],FormatType_]^:=Format[" ",FormatType];
>
> Format[Continuation[_]]:=" ";
> ```

This means any argument passed to `Continuation` displays as a single white space in the front end:

```
In[1] := Continuation[Cos[x]]

Out[1] = (*  *)
```

Does anyone know what purpose this symbol serves?

Comment: [`\[Continuation]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Continuation.html) is also the name of the special character used to indicate that input should be interpreted as continuing in the next line, or to break output too long for the current window. I don't see an obvious connection with the function in your question though, since it wouldn't seem right to format that symbol as a space in all situations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Citing [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1996/Dec/msg00139.html) 1996 year MathGroup post by Dave Wagner,

> A similar function, `Continuation[n]`, is called to format the
>   character at the beginning of continued lines.  So, for example, the
>   definition
>
> ```
>  Format[Continuation[n_]] := StringForm["(``)",n]
> ```
>
> would place a line number inside of parentheses on the second and
>   subsequent lines of a multi-line output.

More specifically, this function is called during formatting of multi-line output for the purposes of displaying it within the terminal interface (i.e. when you work interactively with `math.exe` or `WolframKernel.exe`) and also when you request the `OutputForm` format within the notebook interface. Using the example provided by Dave (and working within the notebook interface),

```
Format[Continuation[n_]] := StringForm["(``)", n]

200! // OutputForm
```

> ```
> 78865786736479050355236321393218506229513597768\ 
> (2) 7173263294742533244359449963403342920304284\ 
> (3) 0119846239041772121389196388302576427902426\ 
> (4) 3710506192662495282993111346285727076331723\ 
> (5) 7396988943922445621451664240254033291864131\ 
> (6) 2274282948532775242424075739032403212574055\ 
> (7) 7956866022603190417032406235170085879617892\ 
> (8) 2222789623703897374720000000000000000000000\ 
> (9) 000000000000000000000000000
> ```

You may be also interested in the function `StringBreak` described by Dave in the same post:

> There is a function called `StringBreak` that you can override to do
>   this. (For some reason, this function was documented in version 2 but
>   has been dropped from the documentation in version 3).
>
> `StringBreak[n]` is called to format the n'th line-breaking character in
>   a multiline output. So you can define
>
> ```
>  Format[StringBreak[_]] := ""
> ```
>
> to eliminate all the line-breaking characters.

After evaluating

```
Format[StringBreak[_]] := ""
```

in a fresh kernel, we get

```
200! // OutputForm
```

> ```
> 7886578673647905035523632139321850622951359776871 
>   73263294742533244359449963403342920304284011984 
>   62390417721213891963883025764279024263710506192 
>   66249528299311134628572707633172373969889439224 
>   45621451664240254033291864131227428294853277524 
>   24240757390324032125740557956866022603190417032 
>   40623517008587961789222227896237038973747200000 
>   00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> ```

The same way these functions work in the actual terminal mode:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

These functions aren't called on `Export`, `Write`, `WriteString` etc. even when the `OutputForm` wrapper is used:

```
Format[StringBreak[_]] := ""
Format[Continuation[n_]] := StringForm["(``)", n]

str = OpenWrite[];
Write[str, OutputForm[200!]];
Close[str];
FilePrint[%]
```

> ```
> 78865786736479050355236321393218506229513597768717326329474253324435944996340\
> 33429203042840119846239041772121389196388302576427902426371050619266249528299\
> 31113462857270763317237396988943922445621451664240254033291864131227428294853\
> 27752424240757390324032125740557956866022603190417032406235170085879617892222\
> 2789623703897374720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> ```

Answer (score 7):

`\[Continuation]` is also the name of the special character used to indicate that input should be interpreted as continuing in the next line, or to break output too long for the current window. I suspect `Continuation[]` to be the operator form of that infix symbol.

On second thought, I suspect that the formatting references you found are linked to special situations in which the `\[Continuation]` symbol is best / most safely formatted as a space.

In my installation (MMA 10.4.0 on Win7-64), the definitions associated with `Continuation` are found in the following files:

```
$InstallationDirectory <> "\\SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\TextResources\\FEKernelInit.tr"
$InstallationDirectory <> "\\SystemFiles\\Links\\JLink\\Source\\Java\\com\\wolfram\\jlink\\ui\\MathSessionPane.java"
```

The first file seems related to front-end initialization and contains:

```
Format[Continuation[_]] := " ";
```

whereas the second file contains:

```
Format[Continuation[_], OutputForm] = \"\" ;
```

The second file is more heavily commented by its author (Todd Gayley from Wolfram); the line above appears in a J/Link function dealing with the generation / management of window interfaces (as far as I can tell). One of the properties of these windows seems to be the fact that `Continuation[]` is to be formatted as the string "\" in OutputForm. This is, of course, also commonly done by the front end when copying lines that are too long for the set page width.

Answer (score 7):

After a quick Google search I came across [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=SgnKBgAAQBAJ), which provides a description.

[image]

Translation:

---

Continuation[n]

is the result at the beginning of the nth line in a multiline printed Expression. The default value of Continuation is either the string " " or the string ">". The value of Continuation is can be changed with the command Format[Continuation[n_]]:=expr. The Symbol LineBreak will be printed between continuing lines, Indent spezifies the used indent, if a line begins with a subexpression, StringBreak is a Symbol that will be used if a string is splitted in output lines, StringSkeleton and Skeleton will be used for Short or Shallow Output forms.

see also: Format, Indent, LineBreak, Skeleton, StringBreak, StringSkeleton.

---

In other words, Continuation along with some other symbols control text formatting in mathematica. Some of the symbols like Skeleton or StringSkeleton are aparrently documented. The book associates Continuation with "manual formatting", a category which includes the following:

[image]